# python calling function from another file while using import from the main file

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to use multiple files in my programing and I ran into a problem.

I have two files: main.py, nu.py

The main file is:

```
import numpy
import nu

def numarray():
    numpy.array(some code goes here)

nu.createarray()
```

The nu file is:

```
def createarray():
    numpy.array(some code goes here)
```

When I run main I get an error:

File "D:\python\nu.py", line 2, in createarray

numpy.array(some code goes here)

NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

numpy is just an exaple, I'm using about six imports.
As far as I see it, I have to import all moduls on all files, but it creating a problem where certain modules can't be loaded twice, it just hang.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I properly import functions from another file while using imported modules from the main file?

I hope i explain it well.

thanks for helping!

Comment: use packages to deal with circular imports (that is what I guess your issue is with "hanging") (and you can google how to create packages in python, that is something not to explain in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I have years in python and importing from other files is still a headache..

The problmen here is that you are not importing `numpy` in `"nu.py"`.

But as you say sometimes it's a little annoying have to import al libraries in all files.

The last thing is, How do you get the error a module cannot be imported twice? can you give me an example?

Comment: I'm programing something that controls Razer hardware, the library is using http request and sending data to localhost on a certain port (that how Razer API works).
That connection persists and when I run the same library from the other file, it just hang, I guess it's waiting for that port to be free.

Comment: Hmmm in that case you have to be carefull. You migth resolve everithing that call to that librarie in one script. But if you cant, probably you coud use partial imports to workaround that: probably it's only one class that is causing problems, so you create an object of that class and only pass the same object between functions and modules.

I had a similar problem a time ago, i also readed about Singletons to solve that problem (don't remember how it went)

Answer (score 0):

In each separate python script if you are using a module within you need to import it to access. So you will need to 'import numpy' in your nu.py script like below

If possible try keeping the use of a module within a script so you dont have import the same multiple times, although this wont always be appropriate